# Spring JPA globally_quoted_identifiers incorrectly quoting column type TEXT

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm using the property globally_quoted_identifiers to deal with issues of reserved keywords being used for column names in an application I'm maintaining. However I've just encountered a bug, where a create table statement is being generated like so...

```
create table `MyTable` (`id` bigint not null auto_increment, `body` `TEXT`...
```

The create statement fails in MySQL, because TEXT should not be quoted.

I'm not sure why this is happening. It doesn't do it to other column types, bigint, varchar etc.

Is there something else I need to do, to have JPA correctly handle the MySQL TEXT column type?

Update: This is the data class which demonstrates the issue...

```
@Entity
data class MyTable(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    var body: String? = null
)
```

This will result in the above table create SQL above, when globally_quoted_identifiers is enabled.

Comment: I think `TEXT` should be without quotes as it will be mysql column type. You should share your code which is generating above sql.

Comment: @Vivek I've updated the question with a sample Entity declaration. Yes, you're correct that TEXT should be without quotes, but for some reason jpa generates it with quotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you try with below config,

hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers = true
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions = true