# JPA generates incorrect SQL query for MySql8 with columdefinition

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Springboot JPAs to generate a MySql8 table. It works fine unless I try to use the columndefinition in the Column annotation.

```
 @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private Boolean example;
```

I tried replacing boolean with TINYINT but MySql8 should support boolean as far as I am aware.

I get an error during the table generation:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`boolean default false` at line 5

To me it looks like the generated SQL Syntax has additional quotation marks but I am unsure how to fix the issue.

```
 create table `exampleTable` (
       `id` bigint not null auto_increment,
        `example` `boolean default false`,
        primary key (`id`)
    )
```

EDIT:
I found my Issue in this question:
[Spring JPA globally_quoted_identifiers incorrectly quoting column type TEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087403/spring-jpa-globally-quoted-identifiers-incorrectly-quoting-column-type-text)

Comment: This code works for me successfully. Specify which versions of spring, hibernate, mysql driver are used and how you enable ddl generation

Comment: When using hibernate, you can use the hibernate specific `@ColumnDefault` annotation to only specify the default value. That way you don't have a hassle with the data type

Comment: Thanks for your replies! As stated in my Edit, I found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the default value of the example to be false then you can write it like this and remove columnDefintion from there

private Boolean example=false;

Comment: Should've mentioned – I already did that and it is working fine that way. I am just trying to figure out how to use the columnDefinition attribute at this point.

Comment: @Column(columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT false") will work for many databases include PostgreSQL

Comment: @Column(columnDefinition="bit default 0")
    private Boolean active;                                                                                                                      this will work with sql

Answer (score 0):

Disable quotes by adding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=false` to `application.properties` file

But after disabling, you will not be able to use column and table names that match mysql keywords (eg `desc`). Workaround by adding an underscore:

```
@Column(name = "desc_")
String desc;
```